# How to generate random numbers by a certain step?

Tags: python, list, random, multiplication

For school we have to create a program in python in which we generate a given number of random numbers and you can choose by what multiplication. I tried this code (which will show my list is empty) but I'm wondering if there is a specific function for this in python because I cant seem to find out how to do it.

Also, we can't use any other function than randint()

```
from random import randint

list = []
aantal = int(input("Hoeveel random getallen wilt u? "))
veelvoud = int(input("Welke veelvoud? "))

for i in range(aantal):
    getal = randint(1, 100)
    if getal % veelvoud == 0:
        list.append(getal)
    else:
        i -= 1

print(list)
```

Comment: "choose by what multiplication": what does this mean?

Comment: @ScottHunter By this I meant "step", ill correct it in the title

Comment: `list` is a class type in python. You might want to change the name of the variable to something else.

Also, the `i -= 1` lines won't work. The for loop will iterate over the values of the `range` object, so even if you decrement `i`, the next iteration will set `i` as the next number. You  should use a while loop instead.

Comment: @TheNightHawk I used a while function and it worked, I could've just used randrange() but my teacher doesnt allow functions we havent learned yet :/ thanks for the help tho

Comment: If you want a random number that is a multiple of *a* but less than *b*, choose a random integer less than *b/a* and *multiply* that by *a*.  Works *every* time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a different way to approach the problem:

- Request user input for the number of random numbers, and the step
- Create an empty list
- While the list contains less elements than the number requested, generate random numbers between 1 and 100
- Check if the random number is a multiple of the step, and if so, add it to the list

```
from random import randint

number = int(input("How many random numbers to generate?: "))
step = int(input("Multiple of which number? : "))

nums_list = []

while len(nums_list) < number:
  rand = randint(1, 100)
  if rand % step != 0:
    continue
  else:
    nums.append(rand)

print(nums_list)
```

An even more efficient way would be to generate random numbers in a way such that the number will always be a multiple of the step:

```
from random import randint

number = int(input("How many random numbers to generate?: "))
step = int(input("Multiple of which number? : "))

# The highest number that can be multiplied with the step to
# produce a multiple of the step less than 100
max_rand = floor(100/step)

nums_list = []

for _ in range(number):
  rand = randint(1, max_rand) * step
  nums_list.append(rand)

print(nums_list)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `random.randrange`. For example

```py
random.randrange(5, 101, 5)
```

will give a random number in {5, …, 95, 100}.

If you want several of them, the best way is a list comprehension. So

```
[random.randrange(multiple, 101, multiple) for _ in range(count)]
```

will give you a list of `count` numbers 1–100 inclusive, requiring that they be multiples of `multiple`.

So your code can be

```
from random import randrange

aantal = int(input("Hoeveel random getallen wilt u? "))
veelvoud = int(input("Welke veelvoud? "))

print([randrange(veelvoud, 101, veelvoud) for _ in range(aantal)])
```

Note that your original code would not give `aantal` numbers, because your `i -= 1` does not do anything in this context – the for loop overwrites the value of `i` on every iteration.

Comment: You missed the comment: "... I could've just used randrange() but my teacher doesnt allow functions we havent learned yet"

Comment: @ScottHunter Ah, yes. The question was ‘is a specific function for this in python’, though, so if `randrange` is banned there it seems to me there isn’t really an answer: it’s a bit like ‘What’s 2 + 2, but not 4?’.

Answer (score -2):

I did a bit of research and I think this is the easiest and most used/known method.
You can bring a bit more randomness into it when you multiply two random numbers but idk, seems weird to me.

Comment: This is a *terrible* method, both because it is implemented incorrectly *and* it is unnecessarily inefficient.

Comment: yeah, not the biggest fan either

Comment: So thank you for correcting me. It is the method I have used myself and seen many many times. Can you tell me what method is better?